# Need to manipulate field values using UNPIVOT by referencing the column names being unpivoted

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

I'm new to stackoverflow and new to UNPIVOT so I apologize if the answer is out there somewhere, but I can't find it - perhaps I don't know how to word it properly.  Also please forgive me lack of knowledge on h

I have values in a table BUDGET_INFO containing financial information for each month in a single row.

```
BUD_PROJ    BUD_ACCT   BUD_SUB_ACCT    BUD_YEAR    BUD_MONTH_01    BUD_MONTH_02    BUD_MONTH_03   
1           10000      01              2015        1000            2000            3000
```

I was able to get it as such

```
BUD_PROJ    BUD_ACCT   BUD_SUB_ACCT    BUD_YEAR   AMOUNT
1           1000       01              2015       1000
1           1000       01              2015       2000
1           1000       01              2015       3000
```

The problem is, I need to know what month the values come from.  End result needs to be:

```
BUD_PROJ    BUD_ACCT   BUD_SUB_ACCT    BUD_YEAR    VALUE
1           1000       01              201501      1000
1           1000       01              201502      2000
1           1000       01              201503      3000
```

Not all monthly column values will be populated, so I'd like to be able to reference the column name and pull the month identifier ('01','02','03',etc) and concatenate it with the year value (ideally) or just into its own column.  Is there any way to reference the column header from the values in the select statement?  So far I used:

```
SELECT
  UNPVT.BUD_PROJ,
  UNPVT.BUD_YEAR,
  UNPVT.BUD_ACCT,
  UNPVT.BUD_SUB_ACCT,
  UNPVT.VALUE
FROM BUDGET_INFO
UNPIVOT 
(
VALUE FOR ATTRIBUTE IN 
(BUD_MONTH_01, BUD_MONTH_02, BUD_MONTH_03,BUD_MONTH_04, BUD_MONTH_05, BUD_MONTH_06, BUD_MONTH_08, BUD_MONTH_09, BUD_MONTH_10, BUD_MONTH_11, BUD_MONTH_12)
) UNPVT
WHERE UNPVT.VALUE != 0
```

Thanks all.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server, then `apply` can readily do what you want:

```
select bi.BUD_PROJ, bi.BUD_YEAR, bi.BUD_ACCT, bi.BUD_SUB_ACCT,
       v.value. v.mon
from budget_info bi cross apply
     (values (BUD_MONTH_01, 1),
             (BUD_MONTH_02, 2),
             . . . 
     ) v(value, mon))
where v.value <> 0;
```

`apply` actually implements a lateral join, which is available in other databases as well.

If you don't use apply, you can do something quite similar with a bunch of `union all`s, with each subquery selecting one column.

Comment: Beautiful, thank you.  Now I"m researching apply and lateral joins b/c I'm a junkie for new tricks.  I do database conversions for a property management company and little things like this save me hours.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is.  (I added a second dummy sample record to illustrate)

```
Declare @YourTable table (BUD_PROJ int,BUD_ACCT varchar(25),BUD_SUB_ACCT varchar(25),BUD_YEAR int,BUD_MONTH_01 int,BUD_MONTH_02 int,BUD_MONTH_03 int)
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'10000','01',2015,1000,2000,3000),
(2,'11000','01',2015,4000,5000,6000)

Declare @XML xml = (Select * from @YourTable for XML RAW)

Select BUD_PROJ    = r.value('@BUD_PROJ','int')
      ,BUD_ACCT    = r.value('@BUD_ACCT','varchar(25)')
      ,BUD_SUB_ACCT= r.value('@BUD_SUB_ACCT','varchar(25)')
      ,BUD_YEAR    = r.value('@BUD_YEAR','varchar(25)')+right(attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)'),2)
      ,Value = attr.value('.','varchar(max)') 
 From  @XML.nodes('/row') as A(r)
 Cross Apply A.r.nodes('./@*[local-name(.)!="BUD_PROJ"]') as B(attr)
 Where attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') Like 'BUD_MONTH%'
```

Returns

```
BUD_PROJ    BUD_ACCT    BUD_SUB_ACCT    BUD_YEAR    VALUE
1           10000       01              201501      1000
1           10000       01              201502      2000
1           10000       01              201503      3000
2           11000       01              201501      4000
2           11000       01              201502      5000
2           11000       01              201503      6000
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional option - in the sake of time I'm using the top one but I will be exploring this one tomorrow.

Comment: @Gradisek You may dig this one.  I use this technique to create normalized EAV (Entity Attribute Value) structures  cheers

Comment: @Gradisek  There is no shame is losing to Gordon.  I'm not convinced he's human.